# .NET backend server push notifications to Android without middle broker

Tags: android, .net, iis, push-notification

I'm looking for proper direction.
Currently our Android app uses C2DM for push notifications. Now we have a requirement to make our app run on "locked" devices without Google Play and hence we can't use C2DM.

- I read about MQTT but can't find any broker that I can use on .NET side, licensing is unclear on it as well.
- I also hear about XMPP (in comments) - seems like it is similar.
- And now I just found SignalR! SignalR is to be part of our server infrastructure anyway and I just learned they have SDK for Android.

So, I wonder what is my options:

1. Free or open source, no 3rd party server
2. Hosted on IIS
3. Client for Android

EDIT:

I understand that whatever library that is - it needs to be able to handle nature of mobile devices. Changing IP addresses, etc.

My client apps tend to sleep and get messages infrequently. Protocols like XMPP more targeted towards chats if I understand. Do they support client long polling?

Comment: have you looked into xmpp?

Comment: Just looked. I will update question shortly

Comment: the thing with not being able to use GCM is that you wont really have anything that will awake your app from Doze mode so keep that into consideration

Comment: Right.. Can't I run background service with listener of some sort?

Comment: if you have your service running in the foreground that would probably work. xmpp isnt much different from GCM, I used it for simulating push notifications in a project

Comment: yes you can run a background service that keeps a connection open to your server (long polling, websockets, http streaming, xmpp, or interval polling) that could do something when data is present

Comment: Just edited question again. SignalR might be our option as well - they do very similar thing..

Comment: The fact that makes GCM so special (with the capabilities to wakeup other apps and being unaffected with sleep modes) is that it runs as a system level service. If you want to do that with your own service (to prevent the OS to kill it) then your service should run as a system level service (like the system apps that came with your OS). You can do that if you have a rooted device I think (or a custom ROM that let you that).

Comment: @josemgu91 Those are controlled/locked devices. We won't be able to do custom ROM, but we know that device will be ON pretty much all the time. When device is NOT on - it's not critical to receive notifications. It is OK if client will re-connect with server when device ON (in service) or when app started.

Comment: @katit It's not about if the device is powered or not. Android tend to kill the background services of non system apps when the system is with constrained resources (like when it needs more RAM, has low power, etc.). If you want to do your own service push service and can't install it as a system service, best you can do is to use it in your app but as a foreground service (because Android gives it higher priority than normal services).

Comment: My main service foreground service anyway. On those device we won't have issues with memory or power so it's all should be OK. Problem is what to choose :)